# Non-rectangular images

Tags: image, whitespace

Is there a way to place an image with a non-rectangular area on a page? For instance, an image shaped like so:

```
   ____
  |    |
  |    |  Place links, etc. here
  |    |_________________________
  |                              |
  |______________________________|
```

I realize one could use absolute positioning and simply place the text over the whitespace in the image, but I'd rather avoid that solution.

Comment: Is this for Android or MySQL?

Comment: Images are always rectangular, how are you creating anything different?  Are you looking for [image maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)?

Comment: Even with an image map the original image is still a rectangle. The only way to place it over the top is to use positioning. Or seperate into multiple images, float the top part left and put the other part at the bottom.

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant but it seems pretty obvious I'm referring to HTML/CSS.

Comment: An image map actually might work for this, in that you could just make the links a part of the image. Although you couldn't change the links without editing the image, which would be a pain.

Comment: I did think about using multiple images, I'll probably go that route. Still, I wanted to know if this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your image rectangular as normal, with the dimensions set to encompass the area where you want your links/text/whatever to appear, and just make the link/text/whatever's area transparent (or the same color as your background), then create a div like so:

```
  <div style="background: url('yourimage.png') no-repeat;  padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 50px;">Links and text go here</div>
```

(assuming your area for text/whatever is 150 pixels from the left, 50 pixels from the top of the image)

Comment: You're welcome.  One thing I forgot to mention is that you may want to set the div's width and height to be equal to the width and height of the image.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in HTML then I don't believe this is possible other than to use the solution you already suggested.
Or butcher your image and use this solution:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/raggedfloat/demo.html